# Trying to run Word Embeddings Benchmarks and getting UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: word2vec

I am trying to run the Word Embeddings Benchmarks from this Github: [Word Embeddings Benchmarks Github](https://github.com/kudkudak/word-embeddings-benchmarks) on word2vec embeddings I've created. I've included a picture of what my embedding file looks like.

[image]

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./evaluate_on_all.py", line 75, in <module>
    load_kwargs=load_kwargs)
  File "/home/groups/gdarmsta/word-embeddings-benchmarks-master/scripts/web/embeddings.py", line 39,     in load_embedding
    w = Embedding.from_word2vec(fname, binary=False)
  File "/home/groups/gdarmsta/word-embeddings-benchmarks-master/scripts/web/embedding.py", line 482,  in from_word2vec
    words, vectors = Embedding._from_word2vec_text(fname)
  File "/home/groups/gdarmsta/word-embeddings-benchmarks-master/scripts/web/embedding.py", line 340,  in _from_word2vec_text
    header = fin.readline()
  File "/share/software/user/open/python/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 16: invalid start byte
```

I just want to be able to get the benchmarks to work properly with my embeddings.

Results of hexdump of header:
[image: Hexdump]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting the error reading the very-first header line of the file (which suggests it's *not* something like a challenging word later on):

https://github.com/kudkudak/word-embeddings-benchmarks/blob/2b56c401ea4bba335ebfc0c8c5c4f8ba6394f2cd/web/embedding.py#L340

Are you sure that you're specifying the right plain-text file?

Might the file have extra hidden characters at the beginning, like the '[Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)'? (Looking at `hexdump -C YOUR_FILE_NAME | head` could give a clue.)

Comment: Yes, I am specifying the right plain-text file. I added a picture of what the hexdump code results in.

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong in that `hexdump` output, but it's also hard to see how that error could arise from that same file. (The first line of the file seems it should `.readline()`  OK, and there's no `0x80` byte in the hex output you've shown.) Can you show the code on/around line 75 of `evaluate_on_all.py` that selects the file path to read? Can you change that code to print the full path of the file it's specifying to confirm it matches what you've `hexdump`'d?

Comment: It turns out it was grabbing the older, incorrect version of the file from a different folder.